# Ввод системы ДУ в GUI для численного решения

Tags: gui, matlab

Всем привет. Может кто то подсказать, как в `Matlab` ввести через `GUI` систему ДУ (или ее часть, например коэффициент выраженный через `x,y`) и передать в файл функцию.

Пробовал так

```
pod = (get(handles.edit35,'String'));
```

Затем в файле функции, подставлял как глобальную переменную.

```
function dy = myeq1(~,y)
dy=zeros(2,1);
global a11 a12 a13 a21 a22 a23 s k pod
%if s == 1
dy(1) = a11*y(1) - a12*pod;
dy(2) = a21*y(2) - a22*pod;
```

Так не работает.

`pod` должен быть равен например `x * y (y(1) * y(2)).`

Подскажите как быть пожалуйста.